# How to read a particular row/cell data of csv into a variable in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to verify a response message of Jmeter request with value stored in CSV file, for particular response message I need to read from nth cell(for ex 10ht row) 5th column data and need to verify with actual response message. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware JMeter doesn't provide such functionality out of the box so you will need to do some scripting.

For example add Beanshell PostProcessor as a child of the sampler where you need to do this verification and put the following code into "Script" area

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;    //necessary import

List lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/your/file.csv")); // read CSV file into the array of lines in memory
String row10 = lines.get(9);    // get row 10, in Beanshell counting starts from zero
String[] cells = line2.split(",");    //split row 10 into cells using comma as delimiter
String cell5 = cells[4];    // get value of 4th column, counting is zero-based

log.info("Cell5 value = " + cell5);    // print the value into jmeter.log file
vars.put("cell5value", cell5);    // store the value as ${cell5value} JMeter Variable
```

The above code will read the content of 10th row, 5th column cell and store the value into a JMeter Variable. You will be able to access it as `${cell5value}` where required.

Demo:

[image: Beanshell CSV Demo]

References:

- [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [FileUtils.readLines()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File))
- `vars` aka [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)